On why the phenomenal world can be presumed to "comply" with standard/classical logic in a classical (not quantum) physics experiment
In order to be able to employ the scientific method, we rely on the phenomenal world remaining consistent enough that if we run the same experiment tomorrow that we ran today then the observed results tomorrow will not contradict today's observed results.
Most philosophers would tend to agree that no such consistency can be "expected" of the noumenal world, since we can't presuppose any properties of the noumenal world.
I'll refer to the following statement as statement A:
The phenomenal world is such that no observations from a classical physics experiment will ever be in violation of one or more of the classical laws of logic.
It seems to me that it would be easy to imagine a situation where something appears to violate the laws of logic but in actuality does not.
Is it important to draw a distinction between things which "appear" to violate the laws of logic versus things that actually violate the laws of logic?
And if you do draw that distinction then aren't you transitioning into making a claim about the noumenal world (that there are laws of logic to be violated in the first place)?
Does it actually make sense to talk about what is actual versus apparent in the phenomenal world without accidentally making a claim about the properties of the noumenal world?
I'm a bit confused about the whole thing, and I've entertained the idea that perhaps this means there is zero connection whatsoever between the laws of logic and any kind of world whatsoever, whether it be noumenal or phenomenal.
But if that were the case, then what would it even mean to "believe" that laws of logic are... true?
Clearly, believing such a thing does not lead a philosopher to then believe that the noumenal will reflect this being the case.
And since believing such a thing also does not lead a philosopher to expect consistency of the phenomenal world, the laws of logic are effectively useless at predicting anything.
So then perhaps something I'm actually wrong about is that it actually is reasonable to assume that the phenomenal world is such that no observations will ever be in violation of one or more of the laws of logic.
Let's suppose then that in fact it truly is reasonable to assume that statement A is true
(For a quick reminder, statement A is: The phenomenal world is such that no observations from a classical physics experiment will ever be in violation of one or more of the classical laws of logic.)
Then which one of the following would be the case?

The reason it is reasonable to believe that statement A is most likely true is the fact that we take it to be true that all of the laws of logic are tautologically true, and thus always true in any possible "experienced" world or phenomenal world.
The reason it is reasonable to believe that statement A is most likely true has to do with an assumption made outside of and irrespective of the laws of logic.


See Uniformity of Nature: it is not a "logical law".

@SimonM Please define your meaning of phenomenal world and  noumenal world. If would also help to shorten and to focus your post on one clear question.

what exactly is meant by "the laws of logic"?

@ac15 the law of the excluded middle, the law of identity, the law of noncontradiction... those sorts of laws

@JoWehler I haven't used any terminology in a non-standard way, Assume the canonical use of these terms, I suppose?

@MauroALLEGRANZA that seems to mean that it truly is reasonable to assume the consistency, but the reason it is reasonable lies outside the realm of logic. Have I interpreted that correctly?

@Simon I am not aware that the terms "noumenal" and "phenomenal" have a standard meaning. It would be helpful for me to read a more clear version of your points 1. and 2.

@SimonM if you're thinking of classical logic specifically, you may want to take a look at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic#Introduction

@ac15 Yeah I'm aware of nonstandard logic systems. But I am indeed talking about standard logic (or "classical" logic, as you've called it). If this entire post falls apart simply because there exist nonstandard logics then that's fine with me but I don't see how that's the case

did you look at the example? it's not simply that non-classical logics exist, but that distributivity holds classically and fails in an empirical context

This is good. Then that means you disagree with the current accepted answer by Musty Rusty. If I'm understanding correctly, your view is that it is not even reasonable to think it is more likely that observations will always comport with standard logic rather than not. Notice I am only talking about what is more likely, which is why I've attempted to put emphasis on what's reasonable to personally believe in everyday life as opposed to what can be rigorously deduced. So if you had to give your guess you'd rather guess that the set of possible observations is not constrained by standard logic?

@ac15 suppose an experiment is about to be conducted, and you're very well-acquainted with the outcome of the experiment because it has been done millions of times. Now suppose that I propose a wager: if you correctly predict the outcome of the experiment then I will give you a million dollars; if you predict incorrectly then you must give me all of your money. Are you willing to accept the wager? If so, then it seems you do hold the belief that it's reasonable in everyday life to expect some amount of consistency from the phenomenal world in select circumstances. All I want to know is why

Quite simply, isn't your belief that performing the same experiment as yesterday will yield identical results a belief that you justify by by appealing to personal experience? It seems likely to me that most people who have ever existed would appeal to something like personal experience, as opposed to attempting to justify their belief by saying something like "well, the fact we can expect some level of consistency in the phenomenal world is a fact entailed in the classical laws of logic"

I believe it would be reason 2. Reason 1 seems circular, while it may be that the laws of logic are tautologically true there is no logical way to verify this without having all experiences of everything.
I find an argument from practicality to be most persuasive; more things appear to have a cause when deeply researched than not, and identifying enough of these causes seems to give us predictive power.
This does not necessarily mean that the noumenal world follows laws, but it does mean that laws are a good approximation of how we seem to experience the noumenal world.

I tend to agree, because in my view statement A is a statement about how the phenomenal world relates to the closed system of logic, which sounds to me like an assumption made outside of logic, since the laws of logic themselves do not seem to entail this necessarily being the case.

The world is how it is, and was that way long before humans discovered logic. That fact that there is an agreement between the nature of the world and the laws of logic is possibly due to the fact that through evolution humans have developed a logical way of thinking, and it would not have been much help to our chances of survival had we developed patterns of thinking that bore no resemblance to the workings of the world around us. Suppose we had lived in a Universe not like ours, one which resembled the hallucinations of a bad acid trip, with no persistent entities or patterns whatsoever- do you imagine you would be asking a question about why nothing ever conformed with the rules of classical logic, or would you have developed some other kind of logic that did align with the cray world around you? It is possible in principle to define all kinds of logics, many of which would not have any obvious relationship to the world around us, so the fact that we have come to think in terms of one that does align with the world should be no surprise.

If I'm understanding correctly... are you agreeing that our intuition that the "world" (as it appears to us) obeys classical logic is merely the product of our human experiences leading us to think that is so?

No, not quite. I am saying that there are all kinds of possible logics, and humans have settled on one that matches reality because that is a useful trait from an evolutionary perspective. It is not that the world 'seems' to obey logic, but that we have developed a logic that reflects the way the world works.

Right. The world is bigger and older than all of our grandiose thoughts about it.

i quite like the answer (and evol psych more generally), but maybe it could mention that classical logic and ordinary (human) reasoning often don't match: think of wason, 'paradoxes' of material implication, etc

Ok I've modified the question so that non-classical logics are irrelevant. This is what I should have done in the first place; it's what I had in mind.

From my understanding the "phenomenal" world is the expression of the "noumenal" world, in such a way, that they present two sides of the same coin: the world is in fact one. Logic stands as a tool to identify how this expression takes place. "Laws of logic" are abstract aggregations regarding how this process works. In this sence, "statement A" is a proposition (inside this context) that "acts as a " or "denotes the" definition of what logic is expected to be.
